# Im trying to load fxml files from package folder in IntelliJ,but still does not work

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have package folder for fxml files and view folder for java files.When I put files into the resource folder I can open them but then I cant link them with mine Controller through scenebuilder,but on the other way when I have it in the same folder as java files called view,It wont start,but allows me to link Controller through scenebuilder.

This is the code:
//Main called ViewHandler

```
package view;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ViewHandler extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        try
        {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MainMenu.fxml"));
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(ViewHandler.class.getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.BLACK);

            //getting the logo in the left upper corner
            Image icon = new Image("logo.png");//logo has to be in module resources
            stage.getIcons().add(icon);

            //setting the title of the page/ parameters of the window
            stage.setTitle("Main Menu");
            //stage.setFullScreen(true);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

//Controller

```
package view;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private AnchorPane scenePane;
    public void switchToMainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MainMenu.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToSelectProjectType(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/SelectProjectType.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToEditCommercial(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EditCommercial1.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToEditIndustrial(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EditIndustrial1.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToEditResidential(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EditResidential1.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToEditRoadConstruction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/EditroadConstruction1.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToViewEdit(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ViewEdit.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToCreateCommercial(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/createCommercial.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToCreateIndustrial(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/CreateIndustrial.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToCreateResidential(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/CreateResidential.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void switchToCreateRoadConstruction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/CreateRoadConstruction.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void logout(ActionEvent event)
    {
        stage = (Stage) scenePane.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

[Error with location of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKLq3.png)

Comment: The path that you pass to method `getResource` is relative to the root folder of all your compiled Java classes.  From the image that you posted, I'm guessing it's the `classes` folder. In any case, refer to: [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Comment: According to your project structure as shown in that screenshot, using `"/MainMenu.fxml"` should be correct. I recommend consulting the Q&A linked in Abra's comment and trying some of the debugging techniques described there. For instance, make sure your resources are being copied to the `target` directory (typically some subdirectory therein). And make sure you're executing your project correctly (as you're using Maven, you should use Maven to execute the project).

Comment: Tried it without the /,still didnt work

Comment: @samosusa try to put your .fxml in the same folder as a package of the main class. (/resources/the-same-package)

Comment: @samosusa How are you _running_ the project?

Comment: Im always running it through viewhandler and I tried to put it into the java folder,I also have fxml files in the target and its still not working,this is the error when I tried to put it into the java main folder:Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\samko\Documents\GitHub\SEP1_ProjectManagementSystem\target\classes
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: ViewHandler.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Comment: @samosusa Try applying the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) (see [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for more information) and then executing the `javafx:run` goal to see if it works.

Comment: @samosusa did you try to put MainMenu.fxml to the `/resources/view/MainMenu.fxml` ?

Comment: Read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other, particularly the "Troubleshooting" section. Post the structure of the build folder as well as the source folder in your question: in particular, are the resources getting deployed to the expected package?

Comment: https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/ may also provide useful information.

Answer (score -1):

**Something about paths:**

1. There are absolute paths and relative paths.
2. All paths starting with a "/" are absolute, All other paths are relative.
3. The root of an absolute path points to `src/main/java` and/or `src/main/resources` directory.
4. The root of a relative path points to the directory of the file it is defined/created in.
   If you define/create a relative path called `hello.fxml` in `src/main/java/com/views/World.java`, the path will point to `src/main/java/com/views/hello.fxml`.
5. Note that classpath and filesystem paths can be relative or absolute.
6. It is recommended to use absolute paths.

**Solution:**

1. Put your FXML files into `src/main/resources/views`.
2. Put your controllers into `src/main/java/views`.

This approach solves all problems. The controllers and the fxml files have the same package path locations and they are placed correctly in your code.

**Why the SceneBuilder does not show the controller in its UI:**

I think this might be a bug in SceneBuilder, I know this issue since years. It does only recognize Controllers in the same package path location as the controller, but it works of you "hard code" the full qualified class name of the controller into the fxml file. The above solution should work nad should display everything correctly in the SceneBuilder.

**Example projects:**

You might want to take a look at this projects I set up and see how it is done!

https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

Comment: [Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
*"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible."* This answer doesn't follow these guidelines, and really doesn't explain why the OP is getting the exception.